# C++ Converting image to integer array

Tags: c++, image, argb, pixel-manipulation

How would I go about converting the pixels in an image (.png file) to an integer array, where each pixel is converted to its ARGB integer equivalent? Not a 2D integer array by the way, a 1D one (where access is through array[row*width+col]).

Thanks.

Comment: If you _really_ want to do this without third-party libraries, you are going to want to become good friends with the PNG specification:  http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/.  After reading that (and related materials), it's just a small matter of programming.

Comment: I advise you not to get close to psychiatric clinics, otherwise you'll get stuck.

Comment: @jweyrich, what do you mean? @James, thanks, i'll check it out.

Comment: @jonathanasdf I was just kidding. Not using libpng or another library to decompress the image is insane. For instance, libpng would give you a buffer[width * height * channels].

Comment: yeah I obviously didn't know what I was getting into :P

I just wanted to learn about how it works behind the scenes, but I guess it's still too early for me lol. Guess i'll go with libpng.

Comment: If you want to experiment with basic image processing, you can try using the PBM format - it's essentially raw uncompressed pixel data written out in a very simple fashion, with a bit of header data, so it's trivial to read/write images yourself from code. Look up IrfanView as an image-viewer for the format (and everything else under the sun!). http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pbm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have read image data to some buffer, ordinary cast should do the trick:

```
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file ("image.png", NULL);
unsigned char *pixels = gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels (pixbuf);
int *array = reinterpret_cast<int*>(pixels);
```

Example uses GdkPixbuf library, but other libraries should be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are doing it for interest and learning, I would recommend you do use a third party library, for example [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).
This will save you time (and avoid bugs)

Comment: Time passes and now it exists more than one API for ImageMagick. The C++ one is [Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/).